# Avoid creating duplicate objects from subclasses of a given model in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, subclass

I have a model `group.rb` with subclasses `organization.rb`, `company.rb`, etc. I'm wondering if there is a way to create an organization with the name "Rails Beginners Society" without also creating a company with the name "Rails Beginners Society"? As it stands right now it looks like if I do something like `Organization.find_or_create_by_name(:name => @profile.organization)` I end up not only creating an organization, but also a company and all the other subclasses of `group.rb` with the name I supply in my Controller.

Any ideas/guidance would be much appreciated!

My Models look like this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Organization < Group
end
```

Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is STI (Single Table Inheritance). Rails does support this.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Organization < Group
end
```

etc...

If you have a column `type` in your `groups` table, Rails should handle everything for you.

Comment: That's what my models look like but I don't think I have the `type` column. Thanks!

Comment: I've added the `type` column to my `Groups` model. Do I need to do anything in my controller to specify the type?

Comment: No, if you do something like `Organization.create!(params[:organization])`, Rails will create a record in the groups table, with `type` automatically set to `Organization`.